# Asynchronous FromRawSql to call a stored procedure that returns a single record in EF Core 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0, fromsqlraw

I just found this way to call a stored procedure that returns a single record but I have to do it synchronously

[image]

If I try to do it asynchronously using `FromRawSql().FirstOrDefault()` I get this error:

> "Employee" does not contain a definition for "GetAwaiter" or an accessible "GetAwaiter" extension method that accepts a first argument of type "Employee" (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Any ideas, please?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` instead.

Comment: If I try this I get this error: 'FromSql' or 'SqlQuery' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it. Consider calling 'AsEnumerable' after the method to perform the composition on the client side.

Comment: Ok, sorry, haven't noticed `AsEnumerable()` (putting code instead of pictures would help us). Try `(await ......ToListAsync()).FirstOrDefault()` then.

Comment: But in that case I'm getting a list when I know the procedure only returns a single record, it's a bit like cheating isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. But there is no other "out of the box" EFC solution. The async equivalent of your code is `FromSql(...).AsAsyncEnumerable().FirstOrDefault()`, but it needs another package [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive.Async/) as explained in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/async#client-side-async-linq-operators